# get index of class element with inline onclick - pure js no jQuery

Tags: javascript, class

so i have some class-elements:

```
<span class="show" onclick="show()">show</span>
<span class="show" onclick="show()">show</span>
<span class="show" onclick="show()">show</span>
```

when i click one of these elements i need the index for some reason. i know how to use jQuery, but thats not what i am asking for, here.

my js function should look something like this:

```
function show() {
    var index = document.getElementsByClassName('show')[??];
    alert(index);
}
```

How is that possible with pure javascript? **NOTE: i have to stick with the onclick="show()"** that cannot be changed.

i hope someone can help, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Cant you do show(this) ?

Comment: You should use `addEventListener`. That way you will be able to use `this`

Comment: i could do show(this), but how can use that to achieve what i want?

Comment: i'm slightly new to programming, so my problem with the eventListener and jQuery is, that my <span> elements are generated inside an iframe during my user does something on the page. that makes is hard for me to use jQuery.click and addEventListener

Comment: You do **not** need to use `onclick="show()"` for dynamic elements if you use delegated event handling. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185902/1541563) for how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the array of all the elements and find the current element who received the click

```js
function show(el) {
  var els = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByClassName('show'), 0 );
  console.log(els.indexOf(event.currentTarget));
}
```

```html
<span class="show" onclick="show(this)">span 1</span>
<span class="show" onclick="show(this)">span 2</span>
<span class="show" onclick="show(this)">span 3</span>
```

Comment: that does exactly what i want, so far. thanks for that :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

- Use `addEventListener` to bind event handlers. This will allow you to use `this`.
- If you still need index of element, you can either loop over elements or convert NodeList into array and then use `Array.indexOf`

#### Sample

**Onclick**

```js
function show(self){
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.show');
  console.log(Array.from(spans).indexOf(self))
}
```

```html
<span class="show" onclick="show(this)">show</span>
<span class="show" onclick="show(this)">show</span>
<span class="show" onclick="show(this)">show</span>
```

**addEventListener**

```js
function show(){
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.show');
  console.log(Array.from(spans).indexOf(this))
}

function registerEvent(){
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.show');
  for(var i = 0; i< spans.length; i++){
    spans[i].addEventListener("click", show)
  }
}

registerEvent();
```

```html
<span class="show" >show</span>
<span class="show" >show</span>
<span class="show" >show</span>
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out, that works for me, too! i'll stick with the other answer, though, since it's a little less of code. thanks anyways!

Comment: @MaxSchlesag Thats alright. I'm glad I was able to help in any way. Have a good day. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely insist on using the `onclick` attribute (even though you don't really need to):

```js
// get live collection so you only need to call this once
var liveCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('show');

function show(event) {
    // convert liveCollection to array for `.indexOf()`

    // either ES6
    var shows = [...liveCollection];
    // or ES5
    var shows = Array.prototype.slice.call(liveCollection);

    var index = shows.indexOf(event.currentTarget);

    alert(index);
}
```

```css
.show {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="show" onclick="show(event)">show</span>
<span class="show" onclick="show(event)">show</span>
<span class="show" onclick="show(event)">show</span>
```

However, I would rather recommend you use [delegated events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) to handle dynamically added elements, as using the `onclick` attribute is considered bad practice, [but don't just take my word for it.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/86589/212643)

```js
// see below for how to select the best container
var container = document.body;

// single event listener for all dynamically added elements
container.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('show')) {
        show.call(event.target, event);
    }
});

// get live collection so you only need to call this once
var liveCollection = container.getElementsByClassName('show');

function show(event) {
    // convert liveCollection to array for `.indexOf()`

    // either ES6
    var shows = [...liveCollection];
    // or ES5
    var shows = Array.prototype.slice.call(liveCollection);

    // this === event.target
    var index = shows.indexOf(this);

    alert(index);
}
```

```css
.show {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span class="show">show</span>
<span class="show">show</span>
<span class="show">show</span>
```

The nice thing about delegated event handling is you don't need an `onclick` attribute to handle dynamically added elements, so this will work best for your particular usage.

It is recommended, but not necessary, that the event listener for the delegated events is attached to the most immediate `container` of all the dynamically added elements, so that the `click` event doesn't have to bubble up all the way to the `document.body`. This makes the handling more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

If you're JUST looking for the index, you can pass that to the show() method.

```
<span class="show" onclick="show(0)">show</span>
<span class="show" onclick="show(1)">show</span>
<span class="show" onclick="show(2)">show</span>
```

Comment: that is not possible since the elements are generated automatically, sometimes there are a few deleted, too. so i can't set the indexes myself