# How to get index of current cell

Tags: javascript

I have a table and a function.
I can take cell's parameters.

I'm new in JS. Please help to find index of current cell. Thank you

```js
function changePosition(currentCell) {
   let top = currentCell.offsetTop
   
   //need to find index of cell
}
```

```html
<table class="square-table">
          <tr>
            <td onmouseover = 
      "changePosition(this)"></td>
            <td onmouseover = 
      "changePosition(this)"></td>
            <td onmouseover = 
      "changePosition(this)"></td>
            <td onmouseover = function() {
      "changePosition(this)"></td>            
          </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. I will saw that's not a valid HTML table.

Comment: `function() {
      changePosition(this) `

need a closing `}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get index of class element with inline onclick - pure js no jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185632/get-index-of-class-element-with-inline-onclick-pure-js-no-jquery). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185902/1541563), which provides methods that avoid the bad practice of using the `onmouseover` attribute. Use `.addEventListener('mouseover', ...)` on the table to delegate the event from each `<td>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here

[link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tabledata_cellindex.asp)

```js
function changePosition(currentCell) {
   let top = currentCell.offsetTop
   currentCell.cellIndex
   
   //need to find index of cell
}
```

My problem is resolved. Sorry